# Who drops Unkempt Harold?

Tags: borderlands-2

I played Borderlands 2 on the PS3, now I bought it for the PC as well cause I love it that much. A gun that was close to my heart was "Unkempt Harold" I was wondering, who do you kill in order to get that gun and where?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"The [Unkempt Harold](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Unkempt_Harold) is obtained randomly from any suitable loot source but has an increased chance to drop from [Savage Lee](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Savage_Lee). It can also be purchased from a [Torgue vending machine](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Torgue_vending_machine) as the Item of the Day."

- [Borderlands Wiki, "Unkempt Harold" article](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Unkempt_Harold)

If you're using [Gibbed's Save Editor](http://blog.gib.me/category/games/borderlands-2/), you can also add it into your backpack by pasting the following code: `BL2(hwAAAADKbQCFBwVACAEE2sN4hWEQQwHG/////xow/v8fxECCcRHj)` in the save editor. Make sure to sync its level (Manufacturer Grade) to be equal or lower to yours so you can use it. The code will add a "Double Penetrating Unkempt Harold" (will fire two spreads with one shot).

Its special parts are:

- Balance: GD_Weap_Pistol.A_Weapons_Legendary.Pistol_Torgue_5_Calla
- Barrel: GD_Weap_Pistol.Barrel.Pistol_Barrel_Torgue_Calla
- Material: GD_Weap_Pistol.ManufacturerMaterials.Mat_Torgue_5_Legendary

Comment: Does Gibbed's Save Editor work on original Steam games (Borderlands 2) or does it only work on pirated ones?

Comment: @ikabod197 It's not a pirate copy-only tool. It works on legitimate copies of Borderlands 2. See also: [How do I set my level, unlocked weapon equip slots and playthrough mode?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/111815/4797)

Comment: Coooll!!! I am scared to use it doe, cause Steam might see and stuff, really safe to use? (just makin precautions hehe)

Comment: Ok I figured out on how to use it. THANK YOU SOOOO MUCHH!!!!!! :D WORDS CANNOT EXPRESS. :D

Comment: @ikabod197 I believe it's safe to use. I haven't heard of anyone getting detected or banned in Steam for using it. I'm glad it helped you. Make sure to make a backup of your save files, so you can revert to an earlier save in case there are any issues.