# How can I play a new character with the same progress as my old one?

Tags: borderlands-2

Is there a way to play with another character without having to start all over again in Borderlands 2?

Comment: I'd suggest this is effectively a duplicate of [How do I set my level, unlocked weapon equip slots and playthrough mode?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/111815/11920), since the only way to do so is to use a save editor (which that question/answer shows how to do)

Comment: Basically, the answer is: no, because you can't start at arbitrary point of the game being level 1.